# unable to create docker image in minikube's docker daemon

Tags: docker, ubuntu, minikube

I'm trying to add an image to the Docker daemon running inside my Minikube, so it can be Pulled locally for Development purposes.

First I check the list of *local* installed Docker images

```
user@kubetest:~/workspace$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
tomcat              9.0                 d5eef28cf41d        2 days ago          647MB
tomcat              latest              d5eef28cf41d        2 days ago          647MB
node                slim                05f62d57259e        6 days ago          167MB
hello-world         latest              bf756fb1ae65        8 months ago        13.3kB
tomcat              8.0                 ef6a7c98d192        24 months ago       356MB
```

Check minikube config:

```
user@kubetest:~/workspace/local-minikube-docker$ minikube docker-env 
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/home/user/.minikube/certs"
export DOCKER_API_VERSION="1.35"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

Now I run the command to use Docker environment inside Minikube:

```
user@kubetest:~/workspace$ eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

Now create the Docker image:

```
user@kubetest:~/workspace$ cd local-minikube-docker/
user@kubetest:~/workspace/local-minikube-docker$ sudo docker build -t nodejs-server .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  69.12kB
Step 1/5 : FROM node:slim
 ---> 05f62d57259e
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /usr/home
 ---> Running in 2d9e3d363188
Removing intermediate container 2d9e3d363188
 ---> 4c862acc9863
Step 3/5 : COPY index.js .
 ---> 2368cfc6ca5b
Step 4/5 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Running in 61e1081d2f21
Removing intermediate container 61e1081d2f21
 ---> f99db8ab886d
Step 5/5 : CMD ["node", "index.js"]
 ---> Running in b1f3de55de63
Removing intermediate container b1f3de55de63
 ---> 2ea9d8cf073a
Successfully built 2ea9d8cf073a
Successfully tagged nodejs-server:latest
```

Now check list of 'local' Docker images - it should NOT be here?

```
user@kubetest:~/workspace/local-minikube-docker$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nodejs-server       latest              2ea9d8cf073a        5 seconds ago       167MB
tomcat              9.0                 d5eef28cf41d        2 days ago          647MB
tomcat              latest              d5eef28cf41d        2 days ago          647MB
node                slim                05f62d57259e        6 days ago          167MB
hello-world         latest              bf756fb1ae65        8 months ago        13.3kB
tomcat              8.0                 ef6a7c98d192        24 months ago       356MB
```

SSH Into minikube and check list of Docker images - it *should* be here?

```
           _         _  ( )           ( )           
  ___ ___  (_)  ___  (_)| |/')  _   _ | |_      __  
/' _ ` _ `\| |/' _ `\| || , <  ( ) ( )| '_`\  /'__`\
| ( ) ( ) || || ( ) || || |\`\ | (_) || |_) )(  ___/
(_) (_) (_)(_)(_) (_)(_)(_) (_)`\___/'(_,__/'`\____)

$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
kubernetesui/dashboard                     v2.0.0-beta3        6feddba9df74        13 months ago       75.3MB
kubernetesui/metrics-scraper               v1.0.1              709901356c11        13 months ago       40.1MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy-amd64                v1.10.0             bfc21aadc7d3        2 years ago         97MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler-amd64            v1.10.0             704ba848e69a        2 years ago         50.4MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager-amd64   v1.10.0             ad86dbed1555        2 years ago         148MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver-amd64            v1.10.0             af20925d51a3        2 years ago         225MB
k8s.gcr.io/etcd-amd64                      3.1.12              52920ad46f5b        2 years ago         193MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-addon-manager              v8.6                9c16409588eb        2 years ago         78.4MB
k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64     1.14.8              c2ce1ffb51ed        2 years ago         41MB
k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64           1.14.8              6f7f2dc7fab5        2 years ago         42.2MB
k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64          1.14.8              80cc5ea4b547        2 years ago         50.5MB
k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64                     3.1                 da86e6ba6ca1        2 years ago         742kB
k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64      v1.8.1              e94d2f21bc0c        2 years ago         121MB
gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner    v1.8.1              4689081edb10        2 years ago         80.8MB
$
```

Why doesn't the image get added to minikube's Docker after I've set the environment?

NOTE: I have also tried `eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)` as recommended elsewhere

Comment: Works on my side. Run `eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)`, then , in the same terminal, `docker image ls` executed on the host should display the images from within minikube. This env should indicate the minikube cluster name: `MINIKUBE_ACTIVE_DOCKERD="minikube"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` discards most environment variables, but it's not necessary here.

The only reason you generally need to `sudo docker ...` is because access on the `/var/run/docker.sock` file is restricted; and that's because you can very easily use it to root the host.  If you've set the `$DOCKER_HOST` environment variable, you're not using this socket file, and so you don't need `sudo`.

If you really need to run `docker build` as root for other reasons, `sudo -E` will preserve environment variables.